# How do you add Multiple options to one Mongoose Schema?

Tags: mongoose-schema

I'm having trouble with passing multiple options to the constructor of a Schema in Mongoose.

You can refer to
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#options

Say I have this:

```
const exampleSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    price: Number,
    description: String,
    location: String,
    author: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User"
    },
    dates: [
        {
            type: String
        }
    ]
});
```

and I want to add two options like this

```
exampleSchema.set({ timestamps: true })
exampleSchema.set({ toJSON: { virtuals: true } })
```

or like this

```
const exampleSchema = new Schema({...properties...}, option1, option2);
```

However, as of now, only the first option ({timestamps: true}) will apply to my Schema and the other option ({toJSON: {virtuals: true}}) will not. If I have option2 in front of option1, only option2 will apply and option1 won't.

These don't work Either:

```
const exampleSchema = new Schema({
   ...properties...
}, { timestamps: true }, { toJSON: { virtuals: true }});

exampleSchema.set({ timestamps: true, toJSON: { virtuals: true }})
```

The timestamp is to assign createdAt and updatedAt, and toJSON is to convert the mongoose document to JSON format when using virtuals for that schema.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I figured how to work it out. For anyone wondering:

```
const exampleSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    price: Number,
    description: String,
    location: String,
    author: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User"
    },
    dates: [
        {
            type: String
        }
    ]
}, { timestamps: true, toJSON: { virtuals: true } });
```